# Custom loss function: Cannot convert a symbolic Tensor to a numpy array

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm trying to build a custom loss function with TensorFlow/Keras in Python.

Y_true and y_pred are of the following forms:

```py
>>> y_true
[[[0 0 0 1], [ 0 0 1 0], [0 1 0 0]], [[0 0 1 0], [0 1 0 0], [0 1 0 0]]]

>>> y_pred
[[[0 0 0 0], [ 0 0 1 0], [0 0 1 0]], [[0 0 1 0], [0 0 1 0], [1 0 0 0]]]
```

```py
def loss_iou(y_true, y_pred):
    union = np.where((y_true + y_pred) >= 1, 1, 0).sum()
    inter = (y_true * y_pred).sum()
    loss = 1 - inter / union
    return loss
```

Is there a TensorFlow function that reproduces `np.where()` or, a function that directly computes the logical OR between zeros and ones (e.g. 1 | 1 = 1 and 1 | 0 = 1) so that I can avoid using `where` altogether?

Maybe there's even a built-in loss function that manages this scenario as well?

Comment: There are [`tf.where`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/where), [`tf.math.logical_or`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/math/logical_or) and even [`tf.bitwise.bitwise_or`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/bitwise/bitwise_or). There is also [`tf.keras.metrics.MeanIoU`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/metrics/MeanIoU). However, IoU is not differentiable so cannot be used as loss (directly, at least, see e.g. [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/1902.09630) for alternatives).

Comment: Makes sense! Effectively when two boxes don't overlap there's no gradient for the IoU.